# WordPress appends the_content filtered text inside last paragraph tag of content (rather than after it)

Tags: the-content

Using WordPress version 3.2.1

I've noticed that when I use this filter:

```
add_action('the_content', 'myFunction', 0);
```

The content editor places the content written from "myFunction" **within** the last paragraph tag of the content. How can I force the WP to append the code **after** the last tag?

For example, if my content is...

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

And the "myFunction" routine appends "And this is some extra text" to the_content, the end result in the browser becomes:

```
<p>This is a paragraphAnd this is some extra text</p>
```

Although I want it to be:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>And this is some extra text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter is being applied before `wpautop`, the filter which wraps all of the paragraphs in WordPress content with `<p>` tags.

A value of zero for priority means that your filter will be applied **first**, before all other formatting filters. Try applying your filter later - with a priority higher than 10, the default, which is where `wpautop` is applied.

So, add your function like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myFunction', 11 );
```

Comment: +1 Sounds like a perfect solution (and explanation). Thanks!